# Firebase Storage get download url and store the inside of an array in Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload an array of files (images) to Firebase Storage and then save their download urls inside of one array in Firestore.

```
uploadImages(name, images) {
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      const file = images[i].file;
      const path = `${name}/${new Date().getTime()}_${file.name}`;
      this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file);
      let snapshot = this.task.task.snapshot;

      this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadUrl => {
            this.db.collection('test').doc()....

            HOW DO I SAVE ALL DOWNLOAD URLS INSIDE OF AN ASCENDING ARRAY?          

              .then(() => {
                console.log('Successfully uploaded image.');
              })
              .catch(error => {
                throw new Error('Error uploading image:' + error);
              });
          });
        })
      ).subscribe(snap => snapshot = snap);
    }
  }
```

My code provides the download url for each image, but how do I save them inside of one ascending array?

Answer (score 0):

You can save an array into your Firestore database normally, just by doing something like

```
this.db.collection([YOUR_COLLECTION]).add({link: [YOUR_ARRAY]});
```

where `[YOUR_ARRAY]` contains your download urls. This way you will create one Firestore document containing a field called `link` that is an array of your urls. This document will have an automatically generated ID; if you want to give yourself an id to your document, you would want to do something like this:

```
this.db.collection([YOUR_COLLECTION]).doc([YOUR_DOCUMENT]).set({link: arr});
```

In terms of having that array in ascending order, you will need to organize it first as you wish before you add it.